# Why does this GLFW window crash when it's resized horizontally?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I'm building a graphical program in python using PyOpenGL, and a binding of GLFW for window management. I am using a ping pong system where I switch between two frame buffers, each with their own texture. The issue I'm having comes when I resize the window. I wrote this function to handle resizing calls:

```
def window_resize_callback(window, width, height):
    global fbo1, fbo_texture1, fbo2, fbo_texture2, vao
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    # Read fbo_texture2's data
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2)
    old_width, old_height = glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH), glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT)
    old_data = np.zeros((old_height, old_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, old_data)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    # Delete old framebuffers and textures
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, [fbo1])
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, [fbo2])
    glDeleteTextures(1, [fbo_texture1])
    glDeleteTextures(1, [fbo_texture2])

    # Recreate framebuffers and textures with new size
    adjusted_data = adjust_texture_data(old_data, width, height) 
    fbo1, fbo_texture1 = create_framebuffer(width, height)
    fbo2, fbo_texture2 = create_framebuffer(width, height, adjusted_data)
```

Where adjust_texture_data just centers the data from the old texture into a new one of the correct size.

This is working perfectly fine for vertical resizing, as well as fullscreening the window, but nearly all manual resizing causes the application to crash, with no error message I can see. If the window is set small enough, it can be resized horizontally once or twice before crashing, but this corrupts the texture data.

Through the power of diagnostic print statements (I'm new), I've narrowed down the issue to the line     `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)` in my create_frambuffer function which is as follows:

```
def create_framebuffer(width, height, data=None):
    fbo_texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)
    
    error = glGetError()
    while error != GL_NO_ERROR:
        print(f"OpenGL Error (glTexImage2D): {error}")
        error = glGetError()

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    # Create Framebuffer
    fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0)
    
    if glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        print("Error: Framebuffer is not complete.")
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
        return None, None
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    
    return fbo, fbo_texture
```

I'm very confused, I've been stuck for a week, any help would be very appreciated. Also, feel free to point out anything I could be doing better, I am trying my best to learn and any advice is very helpful.

Here is the reduced code, which still produces the error on my system:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
import time 

def create_framebuffer(width, height, data=None):
    fbo_texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

    
    error = glGetError()
    while error != GL_NO_ERROR:
        print(f"OpenGL Error (glTexImage2D): {error}")
        error = glGetError()

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    # Create Framebuffer
    fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0)
    
    if glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        print("Error: Framebuffer is not complete.")
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
        return None, None
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    
    return fbo, fbo_texture

def adjust_texture_data(old_data, new_width, new_height):

    old_height, old_width, _ = old_data.shape

    new_data = np.zeros((new_height, new_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Calculate the start and end positions of the data based on the texture sizes
    start_x = max((new_width - old_width) // 2, 0)
    end_x = start_x + old_width
    start_y = max((new_height - old_height) // 2, 0)
    end_y = start_y + old_height

    old_start_x = max(-((new_width - old_width) // 2), 0)
    old_end_x = old_start_x + min(new_width, old_width)
    old_start_y = max(-((new_height - old_height) // 2), 0)
    old_end_y = old_start_y + min(new_height, old_height)

    new_data[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x] = old_data[old_start_y:old_end_y, old_start_x:old_end_x]

    return new_data

def window_resize_callback(window, width, height):
    global fbo1, fbo_texture1, fbo2, fbo_texture2, vao
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    # Read fbo_texture2's data
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2)
    old_width, old_height = glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH), glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT)
    old_data = np.zeros((old_height, old_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, old_data)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

    # Delete old framebuffers and textures
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, [fbo1])
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, [fbo2])
    glDeleteTextures(1, [fbo_texture1])
    glDeleteTextures(1, [fbo_texture2])

    # Recreate framebuffers and textures with new size
    adjusted_data = adjust_texture_data(old_data, width, height) 
    fbo1, fbo_texture1 = create_framebuffer(width, height)
    fbo2, fbo_texture2 = create_framebuffer(width, height, adjusted_data)

def error_callback(error, description):
    print(f"GLFW error ({error}): {description}")

def main():
    global fbo1, fbo_texture1, fbo2, fbo_texture2, pause, vao
    glfw.init()

    window = glfw.create_window(1920, 1080, "Test", None, None)
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        print("Glfw window can't be created")
        exit()
    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    width, height = glfw.get_window_size(window)

    # Create textures and framebuffers for ping pong
    fbo1, fbo_texture1 = create_framebuffer(width, height)
    fbo2, fbo_texture2 = create_framebuffer(width, height)

    FPS = 60
    frameLength = 1 / FPS

    pause = False

    glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize_callback)
    glfw.set_error_callback(error_callback)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()        
        startTime = time.time()

        if pause == False:
            # Render to the first framebuffer using the second texture
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo1)
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2)
            fbo1, fbo2 = fbo2, fbo1
            fbo_texture1, fbo_texture2 = fbo_texture2, fbo_texture1

        # Render the updated texture to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture1)
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

        runTime = time.time() - startTime
        timeLeft = frameLength - runTime
        if timeLeft > 0:
            time.sleep(timeLeft) 

    glfw.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```